# did + present-continuous form

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, phrases, expressions, verbs

A conversation between me and my friend:

Friend: I was sleeping when you called. And I do  that everyday till 13:00.

Me: ok

*~3 days later he replies to me at 10:00 already~*

Now my question: Is it grammatically correct, if I say: “I thought you **did sleeping** everyday till 13:00!?” instead of “I thought you used to sleep till 13:00!?” / “I thought you slept till 13:00”

---

P.s Would be grateful if you correct any (english/grammatical etc.) mistake(s) in the question-text itself too! :)

Comment: Your question seems to be based on the idea that "that" in the second sentence refers to "sleeping"; I think it refers to "was sleeping". If so, that explains why we don't say "you did sleeping", but it opens the similar question of why we don't say "you did be sleeping". I have no answer for that but I trust an expert will soon provide one.